# IF ELSE failing in Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am having a simple `IF ELSE` in Procedure but getting following error if execute it:

> mysql> call daily_qip; ERROR 1295 (HY000): This command is not
>   supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

```
DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS daily_qip |
CREATE  PROCEDURE daily_qip()
BEGIN
DECLARE BlockExist INT ;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO BlockExist FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = "GEO" AND table_name = "blocks";
IF BlockExist = 0 THEN 
    SET @BlocksTable = CONCAT('blocks_', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y%m%d') );
    SET @blocks_view = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW blocks AS',' SELECT * FROM ',@BlocksTable);
    PREPARE stmt from @blocks_view;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
ELSE
    SET @BlocksTable = CONCAT('blocks_', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y%m%d') );
    SET @blocks_view = CONCAT('ALTER VIEW blocks AS',' SELECT * FROM ',@BlocksTable);
    PREPARE stmt from @blocks_view;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Any pointer would be of great help

Comment: Do you have tables in format `blocks_year_month_day`? And you create table/view in daily basis?

Comment: Why do you think `IF ELSE` is failing? The error message says that either `CREATE VIEW` or `ALTER VIEW` can't be put in a prepared statement.

Comment: Looks like ALTER VIEW in procedure is not supported. So had to use DELETE and CREATE .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALTER VIEW` can't be done from a prepared statement. See [SQL Syntax Allowed in Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) for the list of queries that are permitted in prepared statements.

`CREATE VIEW` and `DROP VIEW` are both allowed. So instead of altering the view, drop it first and then recreate it.

```
DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS daily_qip |
CREATE  PROCEDURE daily_qip()
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS blocks;
    SET @BlocksTable = CONCAT('blocks_', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y%m%d') );
    SET @blocks_view = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW blocks AS',' SELECT * FROM ',@BlocksTable);
    PREPARE stmt from @blocks_view;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```